# How to remove duplicates from a list in Clojure?

Tags: list, clojure

How can I remove duplicate values from a list? For example,

```
(remove-duplicates ["a" "b" "c" "a"])
  => ("a" "b" "c")
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
user=> (distinct '(34 56 45 34 56 89 11 4 11 78 11))
(34 56 45 89 11 4 78)
```

Comment: Is there some faster equivalent for sorted lists ?

Answer (score 11):

If you don't care about the order, you can simply convert the list to a set:

```
user=> (set '("a" "b" "c" "a" "lala" "d"))
#{"a" "b" "c" "d" "lala"}
```

Comment: In addition to ordering, pushing into a set isn't lazy, but `distinct` is.

Comment: What if I do care about the order? For instance, I want the most repeated in front and so on.

Comment: @noMAD `(map first (sort-by val > (frequencies '("b" "lala" "a" "c" "lala" "a" "lala" "d" "c"))))` => `("lala" "a" "c" "b" "d")`

Answer (score 5):

Dedupe is the faster equivalent for sorted lists since dedupe only keeps the prior element in memory.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about dedupe, and see it's only implemented since clojure 1.7 -- Here's another post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552506/better-sequence-duplicate-remover/25556645#25556645