# Better Sequence Duplicate Remover

Tags: clojure

I made this function to remove consecutive duplicates, but I wanted to know if there was a better or shorter way to express it using `distinct` or something like that.

```
(defn duplicates
  [s]
  (reduce 
    #(if-not (= (last %1) %2) 
      (conj %1 %2) %1) 
    [] s))
```

Comment: Hmm, "I am having trouble to understand what does this function do", yet you correctly tagged the question [tag:duplicates] ^_^

Comment: More idiomatic way to express this `(defn compress [s] (map first (partition-by identity s)))`

Comment: @A.Webb Your implementation behaves differently when the first element is nil.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin Yes, correctly :).

Comment: Do you want to remove *all* duplicate values or just consecutive ones?  The way your fn is written, `(duplicates [1 2 1])` returns `[1 2 1]`.

Answer (score 7):

`clojure-1.7.0-alpha1` has a correct version of this function under the name [`dedupe`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/dedupe).

The one you quoted returns its input sequence without consecutive duplicates. (Almost certainly) unwittingly, it also swallows all successive `nil` values if they begin the input sequence.

```
#(if-not (= (last %1) %2)
    (conj %1 %2)
    %1)
```

The lambda to reduce says: If the last element of the accumulator (`%1`) is unequal to the next input element (`%2`), add it to the accumulator, otherwise return the accumulator.

Because `(last [])` evaluates to `nil` it will never add `nil` values while the accumulator is empty. I leave fixing that as an exercise to the reader:

*Make sure that  `duplicates` returns the expected result `[nil true nil]` for input `[nil nil true true nil]`.*

Note: When operating with a vector, using `peek` performs significantly better than `last`.

**EDIT** (Since you edited your question): `distinct` returns each value of the input sequence only once. Unlike `set` it returns lazy-sequence.

A more idiomatic way to write `duplicates`/`dedupe` is the one that A. Webb posted as a comment (since it is also lazy). Otherwise, fixing the lambda to work correctly with an empty accumulator as its input and using `peek` instead of `last` would be more idiomatic.

Instead of fixing the lambda, in `clojure-1.7.0-alpha1` you would use the `dedupe` transducer for eager evaluation, e. g.:

```
(into [] (dedupe) [nil nil true true nil])
-> [nil true nil]
```

Or for lazy evaluation:

```
(dedupe [nil nil true true nil])
-> (nil true nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

The anonymous function inside the reduce conjs an element to a sequence if it's different from the last element. You could rewrite it like this:

```
(defn maybe-conj [s e]
  (if (= (last s) e)
     s
     (conj s e)))
```

Then you could rewrite `compress-sequence` as:

```
(defn compress-sequence [s]
  (reduce maybe-conj [] s))
```

What this will do is go through each element of a sequence, and append it to the initial empty vector only if it's different from the last currently in that vector. The output will be a vector of the initial sequence with any runs removed. Example:

`(compress-sequence [1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 5 6 6 7 8 9])`

evaluates to

`[1 2 3 4 5 6 5 6 7 8 9]`